# Why does the quantum number n limit the value of l, and why does l, likewise, limit the value of m?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, theoretical-chemistry

Any quantum number that represents the size of an orbital is a positive integer, $n$. 
Any quantum number that represents the shape of an orbital is a non-negative integer, $l : l < n$. 
Any quantum number that represents the orientation of an orbital, $m$, is an integer such that $|m| \leq l$.

Why do $n$ and $l$ restrict the ranges of $l$ and $m$, respectively?

To be clearer, I ask why the quantum numbers limit each other, not what they signify, which is already explained in the related question: [What do the quantum numbers actually signify?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/)

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/what-do-the-quantum-numbers-actually-signify/31641#31641

Comment: @LordStryker, that question explains how to interpret quantum numbers, but does not explain why the ranges of allowable values are what they are. Why for example can $l=0,1,...,n-1$ but never $l=n$?

Comment: @BenNorris Because $l=n$ simply isn't a solution to the Schrodinger equation for hydrogen. I know you know this but for completeness, simply look at the periodic table.  When $n=1$, that means that there can only be one subshell (i.e. orientation) of the $s$ orbital (which there is).  Therefore $l=0$.  When $n=2$, then there are two subshells, $l=0,1$ which corresponds to $s$ and $p$ orbitals.  Furthermore, $m_l=-1,0,1$ since there are 3 orientations of $p$ orbitals when $n=2$ and $l=1$.

Comment: Extremely instructive walktrough: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydsch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may seem that quantum numbers were invented out of the blue, that isn’t the case. They derive directly from solving the Schrödinger equation:

$$\hat{H}\Psi = E \Psi$$

One of the simplest Schrödinger equations is that for a particle in a box — the one most quantum chemistry or quantum mechanics courses start with and therefore found in every textbook for quantum chemistry which is why I won’t repeat it here. But in a nutshell: You need a function that you can differentiate twice and which will then reproduce itself with a constant factor *E*. That can be achieved by sine waves. You cannot say *a priori* which frequency the sine function will have, though: If the box has size *l*, it works for sine waves with the wavelengths $2l,\ l,\ \frac{2l}{3},\ \frac{l}{2},\ \dots$ and the corresponding wavenumbers $\frac{1}{2l},\ \frac{1}{l},\ \frac{3}{2l},\ \frac{2}{l},\ \dots$ or $\frac{n}{2l}$ with *n* being a natural number. *n* is therefore the simplest case of a quatum number.

If you solve this equation for an electron orbiting a proton, the solutions are much more complicated (and there are intermediate steps often presented in the quantum chemistry courses to make the transition easier). However, *n* still turns up as a variable, corresponding to quanted amounts of energy. For certain values of *n*, there are additional variables whose values cannot be derived *a priori* but which can only assume specific values — they correspond to the other quantum numbers.

This in itself is just a solution to a mathematical equation. The real beauty lies in the fact that these quantum numbers can be used to explain experimental observations such as hydrogen’s flame colours. *All* quantum numbers can be used to explain some property one has deduced by experiments.

---

So tl;dr: It’s just what maths tells us will be the case.

Answer (score 3):

The shapes of the orbitals, i.e. the solutions to the Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom $\hat{H}\Psi_i = E_i\Psi_i $, are primarily due to the requirement that all orbitals are orthogonal: $\langle\Psi_i|\Psi_j\rangle=0$.  Orthogonality is made possible by the fact that the orbitals have "positive" and "negative" regions separated by nodes.

One what to think about $n$ is that $n-1$ is the number of nodes in $\Psi_i$. So there can be no $1p$ orbitals since $p$-shaped orbitals have at least one node. Similarly, there can be no $2d$ orbitals, and so on.

Because $s$ orbitals have a spherical shape, there is only one way to orient them, i.e. $m=0$ if $l=0$. $p$-shaped orbitals lie along one axis and there are three Cartesian axes, so there are three possible - orthogonal - orientations (I'm sacrificing a bit of accuracy here for clearness).

It's a bit harder to visualize why there should be 5 and only 5 $d$-shaped orbitals, but the answer is that there are only 5 ways to construct 3-dimensional shapes with (a minimum of) 2 nodes that are orthogonal to the $s$- and $p$-shaped solution as well as the other $d$-shaped solutions.